# Azure Redis timeout with multiple instance of Azure webapp

Tags: azure, redis, azure-web-app-service, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I am using StackExchange's Redis client to read and write data to Azure Cache (C2). During load testing, if I use one instance of the webapp, the redis behaves fine without any error. However if I set multiple instance of the webapp (tried 5 instances with and without autoscaling), I get following error

```
Timeout performing GET {key}, inst: 2, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: {client}, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/{redis_server}, keyHashSlot: 13746, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=26,Free=32741,Min=4,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

I tried increasing the `IOCP` and `WORKER` as well for the MVC project, which does show correct `Min` values but still gives the error.

Log with increased thread looks as below

```
Timeout performing GET {key}, inst: 6, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 1, qu: 0, qs: 1, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: {client}, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/{redis_server}, keyHashSlot: 13746, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=100,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=84,Free=32683,Min=200,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

Any suggestion what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]

The first error indicated that the changes to the ThreadPool hadn't taken affect.  However, the updated error message you recently posted shows that they have taken affect, so that is good.

Now that you have fixed that problem, there are likely other problems that are causing the continued timeouts.  I have documented the most common causes here:

[Client Side Issues](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md)

[Server Side Issues](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/9225f783a40564c9879d#file-diagnoserediserrors-serverside-md)

One of the other common ones I see is that the client-side CPU spikes to 100%.  You have to be careful to look at MAX CPU rather than AVG CPU because AVG CPU can be less than 100% while MAX still hits 100%.  Whenever the CPU hits 100%, you are out of computing power and there are going to be delays in processing the responses the server sent (even if the server responded very quickly).

Comment: Just wondering if you increased Max threadpool counts for IOCP and Worker instead of Min. See this (by Jon Cole): https://gist.github.com/JonCole/e65411214030f0d823cb#file-threadpool-md.

Comment: I did increase the thread with global.asax and I got the proper number in the log however I got the same exception. Let me get that log.

Comment: @joncole I have added the log. Just to let you know, my client/consumer mvc app is hosted as azure web app

Comment: I edited my earlier response after you added more details in your question above.